# How to add shapefile as layer to map using Python and ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, shapefile

I am working on an application and I am a beginner in Python :(

I want to add a shapefile, the execution is successful and everything but no result appears on ArcMap, here is the code I use:

```
import arcpy

try:

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]


    newlayer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(E:\DATA SF\SFcircuit\shape_zizo\batiment.shp")
    print newlayer1
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer1, "TOP")  

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()

    # save the map to persist the added layer
    mxd.save()



except Exception as ex:
    print ex.args[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this line:

```
newlayer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(E:\DATA SF\SFcircuit\shape_zizo\batiment.shp")
```

needs to be:

```
newlayer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"E:\DATA SF\SFcircuit\shape_zizo\batiment.shp")
```

As [commented by @Llaves](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79269/how-to-add-shapefile-as-layer-to-map-using-python-and-arcpy/79270#comment109056_79270):

> r indicates a raw string literal. Without the r, the backslash \
>   indicates an escape sequence, such as a newline.

Answer (score 4):

Just run [`MakeFeatureLayer`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00170000006p000000) in the Python window:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"E:\DATA SF\SFcircuit\shape_zizo\batiment.shp", "batiment")
mxd.save()
```